# Get text of nested childnodes javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

Although I have read many posts on this subject, I am unable to get the desired result.
My goal is to get text of nested childnodes in pure JavaScript.
with this code

```
function GetChildNodes () {
    var container = document.getElementById ("find");
    for (var i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = container.childNodes[i];
        if (child.nodeType == 3) {
           var str=child.nodeValue
           console.log(str)
        }
        else {
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                var str=child.childNodes[0].nodeValue
                console.log(str)                        
            }
        }
    }
}

GetChildNodes()
```

I can get the text if html is

```
<div id="find">
    aaa
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>aaa</div>
</div>
```

But with html code like this

```
<div id="find">
    aaa
    <div>aaa<div>bbb</div></div>
    <div>aaa<div>bbb</div></div>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>aaa</div>
</div>
```

...is wrong.
Could you please give me a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need to get the text node-by-node you can get all of it from the ancestor with [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent),

```
var str = document.getElementById('find').textContent;
console.log(str);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to iterate or recurse through the *DOM tree* looking for *nodeType* `3` and accessing `.data` or `.childNodes` otherwise, e.g. recursing

```
function getText(node) {
    function recursor(n) {
        var i, a = [];
        if (n.nodeType !== 3) {
            if (n.childNodes)
                 for (i = 0; i < n.childNodes.length; ++i)
                     a = a.concat(recursor(n.childNodes[i]));
        } else
            a.push(n.data);
        return a;
    }
    return recursor(node);
}
// then
console.log(getText(document.getElementById('find')));
```

Comment: :I know maybe I'm asking too much but how would i go to change the text of tags that contains b text?Thanks anyway your code is awesome.

Comment: Rather than returning `n.data`, return `n` so you can loop again with your test/action, or perform your action on `n` immediately

Comment: :Thank you again with your idea I could solve in this way:
function GetChildNodes (container) {
 function recursor(container){
            for (var i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = container.childNodes[i];
    if(child.nodeType !== 3&&child.childNodes){
     recursor(child)
    }else{
     var str=child.nodeValue
     if(str.indexOf('bbb')>-1){child.nodeValue='some other text'}
     }
             }
 }
 recursor(container)
}
var container = document.getElementById ("find");
GetChildNodes(container)

Answer (score 2):

Since my purpose was also to change the text in nested elements if the text is equal to a string,
 thanks to the advice of [Paul S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s)
I could solve my problem this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetChildNodes (container) {
    function recursor(container){
            for (var i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = container.childNodes[i];
                if(child.nodeType !== 3&&child.childNodes){
                    recursor(child);
                }else{
                    var str=child.nodeValue;
                    if(str.indexOf('bbb')>-1){child.nodeValue='some other text'};
                    };
             };
    };
    recursor(container);
};
var container = document.getElementById ("find");
GetChildNodes(container);
</script>
```

Thanks again Paul !

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're checking only for the `childNodes` of `find`, and not the childnodes of the childnodes and it goes on.

There is not limit of number of childs an element can have, and so you should have a `for` loop every time or a recursive function.

Why don't you just do: `document.getElementById('find').textContent;` ?

Answer (score 0):

a short version of Paul's answer

```js
function getText(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 3) return node.data; // text node
  if (!node.childNodes) return '';
  let s = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    s += getText(node.childNodes[i]);
  }
  return s;
}
```